# Automatically request change on a PR on Github when certain files change

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

Is there a way to configure a repository such that it rejects or requests changes on a PR when certain files change?

I have a couple of files in an Android project that will not change often like the the color palette. Because the color palettes are defined for us by a UX team, they don't change often if at all.

What I would like to do is if an engineer tries to add a color to a color palette file and open a  PR, the PR should be held with Changes Requested and a comment that explains why the change is requested.

There will be an admin who can let the PR pass if the change is legitimate

Anyone know how or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible through [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), one which [involves pull requests](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#pull-requests)

The [auto-label one](https://github.com/banyan/auto-label), for instance, uses file pattern: you can make a similar action which would, instead of label, change the PR state, accepting/merging it (as [in this action](https://github.com/pascalgn/automerge-action))

Note the Action doesn't fully work on PRs from forks since GitHub Actions for such PRs have only read permissions and can't update the status checks.